# When i click the image to rate the same happen in another rating image

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I created the rating system with 3 images. The problem is that when i want to rate one article(not the first) the same is happening in all previous article's rating image. The rating system is created with JavaScript and article's data are coming from MySQL.

```
<form id="ratethis-<?=$PK?>" action="rate.php?idPI=<?=$idPK?>" method="post">

<div id="rating" class="rating">
<input type="hidden" value="-1"  class="ratingval"/>
<input type="hidden" value="-1" name="rating" class="clicked"/>
<img name="1" src="img/1.png"   />
<img name="2" src="img/2.png"  />
<img name="3" src="img/3.png"  />

 <div>



<input type="submit" value="Submit"/><br><br>
</div>
</form>
```

Sorry! The JavaScript code:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(function () { 
$(".rating").each(function(){
    var id = $(this)[0].id;
    $("#" + id + " img").each(function(){
        $(this).mouseover(function(){
            var index = $(this).index()-1;
            $("#" +id+ " .ratingval")[0].value = index;
            $("#" +id+ " .result")[0].innerHTML = $(this).attr("text");
            for(var i=0;i<index;i++)
            {
                $($("#" +id+ " img")[i]).attr("src","img/3.png");
            }
        });
        $(this).click(function(){
            var index = $(this).index();
            $("#" +id+ " .ratingval")[0].value = index;
            $("#" +id+ " .clicked")[0].value = index-1;
        });
        $(this).mouseout(function(){
            var curretn = $("#" +id+ " .clicked")[0].value;
            $(this).attr("src","img/2.png");
            var index = $(this).index();
            for(var i=0;i<curretn;i++)
            {
                $($("#" +id+ " img")[i]).attr("src","img/3.png");
            }
            for(var j=curretn;j<index;j++)
            {
                $($("#" +id+ " img")[j]).attr("src","img/2.png");
            }
        });
    });
});
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: Sorry, where's the Javascript in here? Can you post some more code?

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are using the

```
    $(".rating").each(function(){
    ...
    }
```

The above code is executed for every selector match i.e. ".rating".

try to generate a dummy class for each of your article and then try with this approach:

```
    $("article1 .rating").each(function(){...}
    $("article2 .rating").each(function(){...}
```

and so on ...

Comment: I have 125 articles that came from MySQL.

Comment: try to pass the "articleX" as a parameter to your function so that you can reuse the function and invoke it many times.

Comment: Please can your be more specific because I'm new to JavaScript.

Comment: Please post the current markup that is being generated for your page i.e. it would help in understanding how you are differentiating the different articles on your page.

Note: Post the generated markup, not the code that you have written.
Tip: After rendering your page in browser, do a view source and copy-paste that code.